# What are some good css and js minimizers for production code?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, jscompress

I'm looking for some applications or websites that minimize css and js files.  Ideally, they could batch them all or if not, one at a time.

Comment: Previously covered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/65491/85414

Comment: Check out the **7 steps solution** described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11624173/863980

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) does both JavaScript and CSS.  I'm not sure if you can send it a batch of files.

You *can* batch process at [YUI Compressor Online (yui.2clics.net)](http://yui.2clics.net/), though that version only accepts JavaScript.  Another [Online YUI Compressor (refresh-sf.com)](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) accepts CSS, too, but doesn't batch.

In terms of comparing the various minifiers, see [jQuery : Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) : How do I compress my code?](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_compress_my_code.3F) Also, check out [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com).

jQuery has switched from the YUI Compressor to [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) for the minified version that they distribute.

Comment: can you send me a link to that?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include links

Comment: Thanks- does the online one allow for css or just js?

Comment: Any library or API that helps in minimize and obfuscate the js and css file using Java?

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq, YUI Compressor (now at http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) is written in Java and works for both JS & CSS

Answer (score 9):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) is pretty cool. You can run it as part of a build process from the command line

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [The JavaScript CompressorRater](http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/).  It does live comparisons of various minifiers (with and without gzip compression) for any JavaScript you supply it.

It also (mostly) works with CSS, though not all minifiers support it and not even all of those that do (e.g. YUI) show up correctly in the comparison table.

Comment: For the record, YUI supports CSS, just not through whatever method CompressorRater is using.

Comment: Good to know, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft released their [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=34488) on codeplex today. Includes an MS build task and everthing inside VS 2005/2008

Answer (score 3):

I like this one from Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 2):

I use [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) by Dean Edwards for javascript.

Comment: The client side overhead of unpacking packed JS tends to outweigh the speed gains of downloading a minified file.  With gzip compression the full source can even be faster than packed:  http://www.ericmmartin.com/comparison-of-javascript-compression-methods/

Answer (score 2):

There's also [a .NET port of YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) which allows you to:-

- intergrate the minification/file combining into Visual Studio post-build events
- intergrate into a TFS Build (including CI)
- if you wish to just use the dll's in your own code (eg. on the fly minification).

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are looking is to speed up your site by reducing the size of the response.

The other thing apart from minified js and css files is you can do a http compress. 
Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827/html-compression-and-seo) and [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Perl as part of your build process, [JavaScript::](http://search.cpan.org/~herrera/JavaScript-Minifier-0.01/lib/JavaScript/Minifier.pm) and [CSS::Minifier](http://search.cpan.org/~pmichaux/CSS-Minifier-0.01/lib/CSS/Minifier.pm) work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the [free tools](http://www.boryi.com/html/free-tools.html) from Boryi

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CombineAndMinify.aspx

Answer (score 0):

YUI compressor is great.

Another tool (and my weapon of choice due to its PHP-ness)  is the PHP5-based Minify project hosted on Google code. If you're on a PHP platform consider it. Rather than running your stuff through a service after the fact, you install and configure this on your webserver once and then code and comment as much as you want and minify will rebuild (reminify) your CSS and/or Javascript on the fly. Yeah. I've used it, works great!!

http://code.google.com/p/minify/