# how to use js-minifier

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, minify

I try'd to minify this little plugin [with this minifier](http://www.jsmini.com/), but it comes out wrong.
(* a.b and c are undefined, etc*)

Does anybody see what's wrong, or is there some online tool too check if it is valid?

thanks, Richard

**EDIT** **PLUGIN is without errors now**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.bar = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.bar.defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

        $this.click(function(e){
            if(!$('.jbar').length){
                var _remove_cross = "";
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){$.fn.bar.removebar();},o.time);
                var _message_span = $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('jbar-content').html(o.message);
                _message_span.css({"color" : o.color});
                var _wrap_bar;
                _wrap_bar   = (o.position == 'bottom') ? 
                 $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('jbar jbar-bottom'):
                 $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('jbar jbar-top') ;

                _wrap_bar.css({"background-color"   : o.background_color});
                if(o.removebutton){
                    _remove_cross = $(document.createElement('a')).addClass('jbar-cross');
                    _remove_cross.click(function(e){$.fn.bar.removebar();});
                }
                else{               
                    _wrap_bar.css({"cursor" : "pointer"});
                    _wrap_bar.click(function(e){$.fn.bar.removebar();});
                }   
                _wrap_bar.append(_message_span).append(_remove_cross).hide().insertBefore($('.content')).fadeIn('fast');
            }else{
                $('.jbar').find('.jbar-content').html(o.message);
            }
        });

        if(o.auto)$this.trigger('click');

    });
};
var timeout;
$.fn.bar.removebar  = function(txt) {
    if($('.jbar').length){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('.jbar').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }   
};
$.fn.bar.defaults = {
    background_color    : '#FFFFFF',
    color               : '#191919',
    position            : 'top',
    removebutton        : false,
    time                : 8000,
    auto:true
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't know the compressor, but you might try [one of the more popular ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702907/what-are-some-good-css-and-js-minimizers-for-production-code).

Comment: thanks, i thought this one was also good, got it from google, I will check it out

Comment: that's not a matter of minification.. your code is buggy.. http://jsbin.com/ipemud/1/edit

Comment: could you post it in an answer, because then I can mark it as the solution. jsbin is a good validator, I did not know that

Comment: I have only one error left, but that one seems legit---Line 18: _wrap_bar = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('jbar jbar-top') ; --- Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the online version of [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) or use the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/) so you can use it for yourself.

Minified version,

```
(function(e){e.fn.bar=function(n){var r=e.extend({},e.fn.bar.defaults,n);return this.each(function(){$this=e(this);var n=e.meta?e.extend({},r,$this.data()):r;$this.click(function(r){if(!e(".jbar").length){var i="";t=setTimeout(function(){e.fn.bar.removebar()},n.time);var s=e(document.createElement("span")).addClass("jbar-content").html(n.message);s.css({color:n.color});var u;u=n.position=="bottom"?e(document.createElement("div")).addClass("jbar jbar-bottom"):e(document.createElement("div")).addClass("jbar jbar-top"),u.css({"background-color":n.background_color}),n.removebutton?(i=e(document.createElement("a")).addClass("jbar-cross"),i.click(function(t){e.fn.bar.removebar()})):(u.css({cursor:"pointer"}),u.click(function(t){e.fn.bar.removebar()})),u.append(s).append(i).hide().insertBefore(e(".content")).fadeIn("fast")}else e(".jbar").find(".jbar-content").html(n.message)}),n.auto&&$this.trigger("click")})};var t;e.fn.bar.removebar=function(n){e(".jbar").length&&(clearTimeout(t),e(".jbar").fadeOut("fast",function(){e(this).remove()}))},e.fn.bar.defaults={background_color:"#FFFFFF",color:"#191919",position:"top",removebutton:!1,time:8e3,auto:!0}})(jQuery)
```

Comment: thanks, uglify worked except for a missing semicolon at the end

Answer (score 0):

Next time give [www.blimptontech.com](http://www.blimptontech.com) a shot for your JS minify needs. Awesome tool, uses UglifyJS. Can even combine files into a single one while minifying it in the process.